# How do I make the music in BeepBox sound like that in early 80's Nintendo arcade games such as Donkey Kong?

Tags: chipsound

I've actually been trying to work this out for quite a while now, since I need to reproduce the type of music found in arcade Donkey Kong for my "Mario" fangame, essentially a primitive, arcade prequel to the original NES Super Mario Brothers - Super Princess Peach: The Prince Rescue.

While I won't really go into any detail with the fangame itself, I will, however, discuss the actual workings for this fangame itself.

Unlike other Mario fangames up to this point, SPP:TPR will actually be one of those "arcade-faithful" fangames that replicate, *exactly,* how the game would've played on real, actual hardware, the exact specifications and limitations of the arcade machine itself, etc.

So naturally, to approach this ultimate design philosophy for SPP:TPR, I'm trying to make the music sound like that of the original Donkey Kong arcade music, etc. The problem is, I'm currently using BeepBox for this sort of deal, and so far, I still haven't been able to figure it out yet.

I've tried setting up the notes in different ways, working with Chords, and even messing around with the Expert FM Settings. So far, none of these things have worked so far, and now I really need help. If you know of a way to make the music in BeepBox sound like that of arcade Donkey Kong's, please let me know. If you simply can't use BeepBox for such otherwise, please describe what else I could do. Finally, the reason I'm not mentioning any specific types of notes is because I want to know how to make the music in BeepBox sound like that in arcade Donkey Kong in general.

Thanks.

**Oh, and by the way, since I'm relatively new to StackExchange as a whole, obviously, I'm not gonna know the entire lay of the land at the moment. If this is the wrong section to post this in, you're free to close this question and suggest the correct source where I can post my question. I sincerely do apologize in advance. Thanks.**

In case if you've never heard of BeepBox before, but especially if you have prominent experience in the field of music, particularly chiptune, here's the link to the actual web app itself to mess around with it a little bit and get used to it. Enjoy.

[BeepBox](https://beepbox.co/)

Comment: I think we do have posts here on 8-bit sounds and music, which is probably the search term you are looking for. I do not know BeepBox, but it looks at first glance to have the capabilities